# Vue: Firebase Auth REST API throws 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

This is the error I'm getting:

```
POST

scheme
 https
host
 identitytoolkit.googleapis.com
filename
 /v1/accounts:signUp
key
 AIzaSyAk1ueCLjDDWCNrt_23o5A4RCfeaYIlN6k
Address
 74.125.24.95:443
Status
400
Bad Request
VersionHTTP/3
Transferred850 B (198 B size)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin
Request PriorityHighest


access-control-allow-origin
 http://localhost:8080
access-control-expose-headers
 date,vary,vary,vary,content-encoding,server,content-length
alt-svc
 h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
cache-control
 no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding
 gzip
content-length
 129
content-type
 application/json; charset=UTF-8
date
 Mon, 24 Oct 2022 12:07:19 GMT
expires
 Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma
 no-cache
server
 ESF
vary
 Origin
vary
 X-Origin
vary
 Referer
x-content-type-options
 nosniff
x-frame-options
 SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection
 0

Accept
 */*
Accept-Encoding
 gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
 en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection
 keep-alive
Content-Length
 79
Content-Type
 text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Host
 identitytoolkit.googleapis.com
Origin
 http://localhost:8080
Referer
 http://localhost:8080/
Sec-Fetch-Dest
 empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode
 cors
Sec-Fetch-Site
 cross-site
TE
 trailers
User-Agent
 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0
```

This is part of the Vue JavaScript code I'm using:

```
async auth() {
  let url =
  'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key= AIzaSyAk1ueCLjDDWCNrt_23o5A4RCfeaYIlN6k';
  if (this.mode=="signup") {
    url =
    'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key= AIzaSyAk1ueCLjDDWCNrt_23o5A4RCfeaYIlN6k';
  }
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: localStorage.getItem('email'),
      password: localStorage.getItem('password'),
      returnSecureToken: true
    })
  });
  const responseData = await response.json();
  if (!response.ok) {
    const error = new Error(
      responseData.message || 'Failed to authenticate. Check your login data.'
    );
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
  localStorage.setItem('token', responseData.idToken);
  localStorage.setItem('userId', responseData.localId);
  this.$store.state.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  this.$store.state.userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
}
```

JSON.stringify is supposed to convert the object into a JSON string, but I'm not sure if this is where the problem is.  I developed my code with help from:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth

Could someone tell me where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue.  The problem arises simply from Firebase, where the user's sign-in password was shorter than 6 characters.